# How to obtain a document identifier from a suffix on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos

I am looking for a way to obtain a document identifier by it's extension/suffix by using either Python, Swift or Command-Line.

For example, having `*.pxm` as an input I am looking for `com.pixelmator.pxm -> /Applications/Pixelmator Pro.ap`. Does anyone have an idea?

I already found `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag` but the Carbon Framework is deprecated and therefore I can't use this.

Comment: https://github.com/moretension/duti

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag` has deprecated since iOS14, so you need to use `UTType` in that case, but if your deployment target is below then you still need to use first one.

Here is simple demo:

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

...

    let type = UTType(filenameExtension: "pxm")
    print(type?.identifier ?? "unknown")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot That's exactly what I was looking for